# Проектирование и структура проекта

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, проектирование, spring-boot

Не могу разобраться как реализовывать структуру следующего функционала:

Стараюсь придерживаться в проекте структуры деления функционала по слоям: Model, DAO, Service.

К примеру есть 2 сущности `Parser` (Парсер) и `Configuration` (Параметры для запуска Парсера).

1. Слой Model: `Parser` и `Configuration`. Класс описывающий поля(атрибуты) сущности;
2. Слой DAO: `ParserDAO` и `ConfigurationDAO`. Логика доступа к данным в БД (CRUD);
3. Слой Service: `ParserService` и `ConfigurationService`. Слой высокоуровневой логики. По сути те же CRUD методы вызывающие DAO методы. Плюс несколько специфичных методов.

В сервисе `ParserServiceImpl` имеет метод `enable(List<Configuration> listConfiguration)`, создающий объект дочернего Сервиса `ParserServiceChild1`, в котором содержится логика парсинга какого-то определенного документа. `ParserServiceChild1` в методе `enable(Configuration configuration)` запускает на выполнение в новом потоке зацикленную логику парсинга. Выполнение становится фоновым.

Сам `ParserService` необходимо где-то хранить, чтобы можно было его выключить, вызовом метода `disable()`. Для этого я добавил `HashMap` (пока сделал так, других нормальных идей не было)

**Проблема:**
Не могу разобраться с тем верную ли я создал архитектуру программы и, соответственно, структуру? правильно организовать хранение дочерних Сервисов `ParserServiceChild1`, `ParserServiceChild2` (в перспективе и других). Пока остановился на `HashMap`.

- Не могу разобраться с тем верную ли я создал архитектуру программы и, соответственно, структуру? Верно ли создавать дочерние Сервисы для описания специфичной логики Парсеров?
- Как в дальнейшем работать с объектами дочерних Сервисов, которые мы запускаем в фоновое выполнение? Ведь для того чтобы остановить дочерний Сервис я должен иметь доступ к объекту. Пока храню в `HashMap` в `ParserDAOImpl`.

*Вопрос формулировал не один раз, так что если что-то непонятно с радостью дополню вопрос, спасибо!*

---

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Отношение между сущностями: `Parser` 1---N `Configuration`. Т.е. один Парсер может запускаться с различными Конфигурациями.

Инициализация Бинов описана в xml.

`Parser.class`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parser")
public class Parser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

`ParserDAOImpl.class`:

```
@Repository
public class ParserDAOImpl implements ParserDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    private Map<Integer, ParserService> mapEnabledParserServices = new HashMap<>();


    @Override
    public Parser getById(int id) {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Parser.class, new Integer(id));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Parser> list() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().list();
    }


    @Override
    public ParserService getEnabledParserServiceByConfigurationId(int configurationId) {
      return this.mapEnabledParserServices.get(configurationId);
    }

    @Override
    public void addEnabledParserService(int configurationId, ParserService enabledParserService) {
        this.mapEnabledParserServices.put(configurationId, enabledParserService);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEnabledParserService(int configurationId) {
        this.mapEnabledParserServices.remove(configurationId);
    }
}
```

`ParserServiceImpl.class`:

```
@Service
public class ParserServiceImpl implements ParserService {

    private ParserDAO parserDAO;

    public void setParserDAO(ParserDAO parserDAO) {
        this.parserDAO = parserDAO;
    }


    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    public void setConfigurationService(ConfigurationService configurationService) {
        this.configurationService = configurationService;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Parser getById(int id) {
        return parserDAO.getById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Parser> list() {
        return parserDAO.list();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean enable(List<Configuration> listConfiguration) {
        try {

            // Обходим все Конфигураций
            for (Configuration configuration : listConfiguration) {

                // Дочерний сервис со специфичной логикой
                ParserService parserServiceChild = null;

                // P.S. Можно было бы хранить класс в БД, и тогда условие (ниже) можно избежать, но пока решил оставить так
                // Если Конфигурация относится к Парсеру с идентификатором 1
                if (configuration.getParserId() == 1) {
                    // Создаем дочерний Сервис, который умеет парсить один тип документов
                    parserServiceChild = new ParserServiceChild1();
                } else if (configuration.getParserId() == 2) {
                    // Создаем дочерний Сервис, который умеет парсить другой тип документов
                    parserServiceChild = new ParserServiceChild2();
                } // Проверка других идентификаторов

                // В объекте Конфигурация меняем статус на true - указывающий что Парсер с такой Конфигурацией запущен
                configuration.setStatus(true);
                // Обновляем Конфигурацию в БД, для сохранения измененного статуса
                this.configurationService.update(configuration);
                // Добавляем дочерний Сервис в "Список запущенных дочерних Сервисов"
                this.parserDAO.addEnabledParserService(configuration.getId(), parserServiceChild);
                // Запускаем дочерний Сервис
                parserServiceChild.enable(configuration);

            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean disable(List<Configuration> listConfiguration) {
        try {
            // Обходим все Конфигураций
            for (Configuration configuration : listConfiguration) {

                // Извлекаем из "Списка запущенных дочерних Сервисов" дочерний Сервис, который работает с переданной в параметрах метода Конфигурацией
                ParserService parserService = this.parserDAO.getEnabledParserServiceByConfigurationId(configuration.getId());

                // В объекте Конфигурация меняем статус на false - указывающий что Парсер с такой Конфигурацией выключен (не запускался)
                configuration.setStatus(false);
                // Обновляем Конфигурацию в БД, для сохранения измененного статуса
                this.configurationService.update(configuration);
                // Удаляем объект дочерний Сервис из "Списка запущенных дочерних Сервисов"
                this.parserDAO.deleteEnabledParserService(configuration.getId());
                // Выключаем дочерний Сервис
                parserService.disable();

            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

`ParserServiceChild1`, `ParserServiceChild2`:

```
@Service
public class ParserServiceChild1 implements ParserService {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void enable(Configuration configuration) {
        // Запуск зацикленной логики в новом потоке
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void disable() {
        // Остановка
    }

    @Override
    ...
}
```

`Configuration.class`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parser_configuration")
public class Configuration {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    // Параметры для настройки и запуска дочернего Сервиса `ParserServiceChild1` и др. дочерних Сервисов
    @Column(name = "PARAMETER")
    private byte[] parameter;

    public byte[] getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }

    public void setParameter(byte[] config) {
        this.parameter = config;
    }


    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private boolean status;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    @Column(name = "PARSER_ID")
    private int parserId;

    public int getParserId() {
        return parserId;
    }

    public void setParserId(int parserId) {
        this.parserId = parserId;
    }

}
```

`ConfigurationDAOImpl.class`

```
@Repository
public class ConfigurationDAOImpl implements ConfigurationDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public Configuration getById(int id) {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Configuration.class, new Integer(id));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Configuration> list() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().list();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Configuration configuration) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Configuration configuration) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Configuration configuration) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(configuration);
    }

}
```

`ConfigurationServiceImpl.class`

```
@Service
public class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationService {

    private ConfigurationDAO configurationDAO;

    public void setConfigurationDAO(ConfigurationDAO configurationDAO) {
        this.configurationDAO = configurationDAO;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Configuration getById(int id) {
        return this.configurationDAO.getById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Configuration> list() {
        return this.configurationDAO.list();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(Configuration configuration) {
        configurationDAO.add(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Configuration configuration) {
        configurationDAO.update(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Configuration configuration) {
        configurationDAO.delete(configuration);
    }

}
```

Comment: вы же вроде бы разобрались со структурой и понимаете зачем нужен Service, `ParserService` не нужно нигде хранить, это просто singlton, состоянием которого управляет контейнер. Вы можете в любом другом бине сделать @Autowired и получить `ParserService` и вызвать `disable()`. Для наглядности не помешал бы код вашего приложения

Comment: @SergiiGetman спасибо! добавил уточнение и дополнение к вопросу

Comment: так а зачем вам хранить сервис, почему вы просто не можете дергать методы?

Comment: @SergiiGetman я видимо что-то не так понимаю. Когда я обращаюсь к объекту `ParserServer`, далее к методу `enable(List<Configuration> configuration)`, то вызываю тем самым создание новых объектов дочерних Сервисов `ParserServiceChild1` и другие. Не совсем понимаю как я смогу обратиться к списку запущенных Сервисов если у меня не будет переменной которая хранит эти самые объекты?

Comment: под фоном вы имеете в виду другие потоки?

Comment: @SergiiGetman да-да, простое создание нового потока. Так каждый дочерний Парсер будет выполнять свою работу параллельно

Comment: и вам нужно эти парсеры останавливать? я имею в виду не дожидаясь окончания работы?

Comment: @SergiiGetman да, в параметрах будет передаваться период вызова парсера, т.е. он будет выполнять работу периодически, например каждые 5 минут или чаще.

Comment: не могу понять логики, вам нужно что-то распарсить, вы запускаете несколько потоков параллельно, но потом их останавливаете. какой в этом смысл? логично просто передать потоку задачу, с которой он должен справиться, а при поступлении новой задачи - передать ее новому потоку. Если вам важна периодичность - то в  спринге есть таски и триггеры  - `scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));` - в 15 минут в начале каждого часа с 9 до 17 с пн по пт. Вам это подходит?

Comment: @SergiiGetman да запускаю сразу несколько парсеров, т.к. каждый "заточен" под свою конкретную задачу и работу со своими конкретными файлами. Можно сказать что парсеры между собой не связанны. Про Таски в курсе, они возможно могут подойти, сходу не смог их реализовать, поэтому оставил это на потом.

Comment: вариант с таксами и триггерами это best practices, думаю что останавливать потоки потом снова их запускать - плохая практика. не советовал бы создавать в сервисе кучу сервисов такого же типа

Comment: @SergiiGetman спасибо за советы! С хранением понял, действительно Таски решат эту проблему. А по поводу сервисов такого же типа, есть ли примеры того как было бы правильно реализовать этот функционал? Сущность одна "Парсер", а реализаций на каждый парсер своя. Я не нашел ничего лучше чем создать "Родительский" Сервис `ParserService` а к нему добавить "Дочерние" уже с основной логикой `ParserServiceChild1`

Comment: по логике ваши дочерние сервисы - это компоненты. просто почитайте зачем нужна аннотация @Service - это должно хватить, соответственно это проецируется на нейминг ваших классов http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html